# mouseover event on two overlapping shapes

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Hi I have two shapes that are overlapping (implementation in KineticJs). I want to change the color of these shapes if the mouse hovers above them. In case the mouse hovers above the overlapped(intersection) area, I want both the shapes to change color. However only the top most shape is changing color.

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepy02/NST8C/ where I want the colour of both rect to be black if I hover mouse over the pverlapped area.

```
stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: "container",
    width: 320,
    height: 320
});
layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
elemOne = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    draggable: false
});
elemOne.on('mousemove', function() {
    this.setFill("black");
    this.setZIndex(10);
    layer.draw();
});
elemOne.on('mouseout', function() {
    this.setFill("red");
    this.setZIndex(1);
            layer.draw();
});
elemTwo = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 150,
    y: 150,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    draggable: false
});
elemTwo.on('mousemove', function() {
    this.setFill("black");
    this.setZIndex(10);
            layer.draw();
});
elemTwo.on('mouseout', function() {
    this.setFill("green");
    this.setZIndex(1);
             layer.draw();
});
layer.add(elemOne);
layer.add(elemTwo);
stage.add(layer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinda solved it by creating a background element and observing `mouseposition` for each move. In each `mousemove`, I calculate if the mouse position is within every element. If yes, then change color. 
Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepy02/NST8C/5/

Source:

```
stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: "container",
    width: 500,
    height: 500
});
background = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    fill: 'white',
    stroke: 'white',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    draggable: false,
});
layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
elemOne = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    draggable: false,
    name: 'elem',
    id: 1,
    col: 'red'
});

elemTwo = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 150,
    y: 150,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    draggable: false,
    name: 'elem',
    id: 2,
    col: 'green'
});

stage.on('mousemove', function() {
    //alert("a");
    var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
    var shapes = stage.get('.elem');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        if (shapes[i].intersects(mousePos.x, mousePos.y)) {
            shapes[i].setFill("black");
        }
        else {
            if (shapes[i].getId() == 1) {
                shapes[i].setFill("red");
            }
            else shapes[i].setFill("green");
        }
    }
    layer.draw();
});
layer.add(background);
layer.add(elemOne);
layer.add(elemTwo);
stage.add(layer);
```

Obviously I am not proud of its performance as for each `mousemove` I am checking each element. Performance should not be an issue if I were to check for `mousedown` or `click`, but I think someone out there in this wide world can provide a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

The mouseover event will fire for the element with greater z-index, so when you mouseover either elemOne or elemTwo  (even when you mouseover the overlap area) and set its z-index to 10, only the element with greater z-index is firing the mouseover event.

How about you delegate the mouseover to 'stage', then calculate whether mouseover offset is in the overlap area?

Comment: Slight issue here... in my app I have many shapes. Thus to calculate I will have to run a loop with each shape to find out if it intesects the point. I was hoping for more performance oriented solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do this by introducing third element which is overlapping plz find on [**fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/NST8C/1/) .

There are some loop holes like ,Can't use Stroke i.e. border to boxes. May be some other also.

Best of Luck.

Here is code

```
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: "container",
        width: 320,
        height: 320
    });
    layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    elemOne = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        fill: 'red',
//        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 0,
        draggable: false,
        globalalpha: 0.5
    });
    elemOne.on('mousemove', function() {
        this.setFill("black");
        elemThree.setFill("black");         
//        this.setZIndex(10);
        layer.draw();
    });
    elemOne.on('mouseout', function() {
        elemThree.setFill("red");
        this.setFill("red");
//        this.setZIndex(1);
        layer.draw();
    });
    elemTwo = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 150,
        y: 150,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        fill: 'green',
//        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 0,
        draggable: false,
        globalalpha: 0.5        
    });
    elemTwo.on('mousemove', function() {
        this.setFill("black");
        elemThree.setFill("black");         
//        this.setZIndex(10);
        layer.draw();
    });
    elemTwo.on('mouseout', function() {
        elemThree.setFill("green");
        this.setFill("green");
//        this.setZIndex(1);
        layer.draw();
    });
    elemThree = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 150,
        y: 150,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
//        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 0,
        draggable: false,
        zindex: 100
    });
    elemThree.on('mousemove', function() {
        elemOne.setFill("black");
        elemTwo.setFill("black");
        elemThree.setFill("black");
//        this.setZIndex(10);
        layer.draw();
    });
    elemThree.on('mouseout', function() {
        elemOne.setFill("red");
        elemTwo.setFill("green");        
        layer.draw();
    });

    layer.add(elemTwo);
    layer.add(elemOne);
    layer.add(elemThree);
    stage.add(layer);
​
```

Comment: though it is a solution if I were to only color the elements, but in reality I need to do some operations on the intersected Ids. Thus for my application this will not work.